# Get view for default view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have sub header to show three different information. My problem now, when i click on the main header, it need t show 2 information from sub header with the condition. How i can get this work. Currently I can only see the information when click on the sub header and when click on the main header it will show empty page. The code to select the sub header i used querystring.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PageSize = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrderPagedResultSize"].AsInt(); ;
            CurrentPendingOrderPage = 0;
            CurrentConfirmedOrderPage = 0;
            CurrentRejectedOrderPage = 0;
            SetDefaultSeoEntities();

            AssignResourceValues();
            BindOrderList();

            pnlPending.Visible = (Request.QueryString["order"] == "pending") ? true : false;
            pnlConfirmed.Visible = (Request.QueryString["order"] == "confirmed") ? true : false;
            pnlRejected.Visible = (Request.QueryString["order"] == "rejected") ? true : false;


         }


    }



 protected void pending(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("OrderHistory.aspx?order=pending", true);
    }

    protected void confirmed(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

        Response.Redirect("OrderHistory.aspx?order=confirmed", true);
    }
    protected void rejected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("OrderHistory.aspx?order=rejected", true);
    }
```

in the aspx file i call this methodas below:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="col-md-12 innerTitle">
    Order Summary
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="account">
         <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="confirmed"><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="confirmed" runat="server">Confirmed Order History</asp:LinkButton></b></div> 
         <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="pending"><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="pending" runat="server">Pending Order History</asp:LinkButton></b></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 text-center" id="rejected"><b><asp:LinkButton OnClick="rejected" runat="server">Rejected Order History</asp:LinkButton></b></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The condition to show in the main header is when pending order is empty then show confirmed order summary if not show pending order summary. An d for information, each summary i used grid view to show it.

The pending page will empty control by below code:

```
private void BindPendingOrderList()
    {
        GetOrdersResponse pendingOrdersResponse = new GetOrdersResponse();
        if (Session["LoginCustomerRole"].ToString() == "Customer") pendingOrdersResponse = GetPendingOrdersByCustomer();
        else if (Session["LoginCustomerRole"].ToString() == "CustomerAdmin") pendingOrdersResponse = GetPendingOrdersByCustomerGroupId();

        PendingOrderPageControl.LoadPager(pendingOrdersResponse.TotalCount, CurrentPendingOrderPage, PageSize);
        grdvwPendingOrder.DataSource = pendingOrdersResponse.Orders;
        grdvwPendingOrder.DataBind();

        if (pendingOrdersResponse.TotalCount > 0) PendingOrderPageControl.Visible = true; else PendingOrderPageControl.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: So, in page_Load pending order is empty it should be redirected to confirmed order is it? explain..

Comment: yes.. when the pending order empty it will show the confirmed order.

Comment: currently the main page show empty, to see the information need to click one by one the information that i set in the sub header. now i need to set in the main page to see either pending order or confirmed order

Comment: how the pending order will get empty? is there any variable to denote that?

Comment: balaji, refer to update post..

Comment: why not to have this `ConfirmedOrderPageControl.Visible = true;` in else part of BindPendingOrderList? if i'm wrong, explain the question with the UI design, upload the screenshots of the header & subheader